# Triangulation of euclidean plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Im trying to understand the following proof of why $H_2(\mathbb{R^2})=0$. I dont understand why the set $X$ is supposed to be open.

Consider the triangulation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ covered by triangles as $2$-simplexes.
This endow $R^2$ with a simplicial structure (in particular all triangles are counterclockwise oriented) and we can consider the associated chain complex
$0 \rightarrow C_2(\mathbb{R^2})\xrightarrow{\partial_2} C_1(\mathbb{R^2})\rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R^2}) \rightarrow 0$

We claim that $\partial_2$ is injective and so $H_2(\mathbb{R^2}) = 0$.
To see that $\partial_2$ is injective, consider a non-zero element
$x = \Sigma_{i∈I}a_iσ_i$ of $C_2(\mathbb{R^2})$. To show that $\partial_2(x) = 0$, it is enough to show that there exist $i ∈ I$ such that one
boundary $1 $-simplex of $σ_i$ is not the boundary of any $σ_j$ for $j ∈ I\setminus{i}$. However if this wasnot the case, the union $X = ⋃_{i∈I}
 σ_i$ would be non-empty, $\textbf{open}$ and closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Since $\mathbb{R^2}$ is connected, it would be $X = \mathbb{R^2}$, yielding a contradiction (X is compact and $\mathbb{R^2}$ is not).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "To show that $\partial_2(x) = 0$" do you perhaps mean $\partial_2(x) \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x$ is a point in the shared boundary of two 2-simplices $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, then either it is a vertex of both, in which case the assumption implies that there is a third simplex $\sigma_3$ meeting the other two in that vertex (to "seal off the edges") and therefore any small $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ is contained in $\sigma_1 \cup \sigma_2 \cup \sigma_3$, or it lies in the interior of a boundary 1-simplex of both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, in which case again any small ball around $x$ is contained in $\sigma_1 \cup \sigma_2$. In other words, $X$ contains open neighborhoods of all of its points and is therefore open while at the same time being obviously compact as the union of finitely many compact sets, whence the contradiction.